# Where can I find a luggage locker in Budva?

Tags: luggage-storage, montenegro

In June 2017 I will visit Budva in Montenegro. I will have a backpack with me. I would like to leave the backpack somewhere and just walk around freely.

Is there any luggage locker in Budva?

Comment: Budva, of all the places in the world? Wouldn't be much more productive and interesting to just spend some time hammering your fingers? Anyway, if you really feel forced to visit it, you don't need to worry about your backpack: it takes no more than 30 minutes to visit it, unless you love nothing-ness. In that case, there's plenty of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feedback to the very same question suggests that hotels and the bus station can store your luggage, as might [hostels](http://www.hostelbookers.com/hostels/montenegro/budva/66831/).

[VirtualTourist member from Saint Petersburg](http://www.trippy.com/vt/Budva-723456-5-10416415/Luggage-storage-at-Budva-bus-station.html)

> If you check hotels in Budva then you will find they all provide storage room service. Try your hotel or [the] bus station in Budva.

Traveler Ava Decage commented on [BusTicket4.me](https://busticket4.me/bus-station/details/Budva/EN/1139)

> Amazing that they have luggage storage for 2€, comfortable benches, WiFi, plenty of food options, toilets for 30¢, great helpful staff, need to pay 1€
>
> Budva Bus Station is located 1.5 km from the old town. 
> Address: Rozine, Budva 85310
> Phone: +382 (0) 33 456 000
> Box Offices Opening hours: 06: 00h - 22: 00h